# How do I use replacement variables when doing search/replace with Regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to search a xml-file for all -tags changing the attribute enabled to false, which can be like this

```
<repository store-diff="true" description="ACS" name="ACS" enabled="true">
```

There are other tags as well having the enabled attribute so I need to search for lines starting with , which is quite easy, problem is the replacement string. I've tried this:

```
perl -p -e 's#^<repository.*enabled="true"#$1enabled="false"#g'
```

But no luck, no changes done to the file I try to change. Or, that's not true, it matches, but I'm not able to change ONLY enabled="true" setting it to false, it removes the rest of the line leaving it with just enabled="false"...

Should be possible according to http://refcards.com/docs/trusketti/perl-regexp/perl-regexp-refcard-a4.pdf

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I haven't tested, but I believe this will work:

```
perl -p -e 's#^(<repository.*)enabled="true"#$1enabled="false"#g'
```

First, you need to have a group in order to use a backreference, so you have to parenthesize the part of the expression that you want to refer to later.  In this case we want everything from `<repository` all the way up to `enabled...` so we enclose that bit in parentheses.

Comment: -1 for a whole bunch of reasons. 1) you didn't tell him to use an XML parser for processing XML data. 2) you use s///g along with beginning of line anchor which can only match once anyway. 3) it will change <repositoryTwo enabled="false" too. 4) $1 is absolutely the right thing to use in the replacement part (you should always enable warnings when developing Perl code). \1 is for use in a *regular expression*, the replacement part is not a regular expression, it is a string.

Comment: Thanks for your notes.  I've removed the incorrect statement about `\1` vs. `$1` - thanks for the heads-up.  As to your other comments: 1) I don't see a compelling reason to introduce an XML parser for a one-line search and replace, especially for something as trivial as this.  This could as easily been done with `sed`.  2) The OPs question contained the `g` and I was trying to introduce as few changes as necessary to make this work for him.  3) The point of the correction was just to point out what the OP had missed (the group), but you're right, his regex will also match similar strings.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me, as this is to be used only one time for editing a config file it does not need to be more advanced. For real XML-parsing stuff I prefer to use Groovy and XML-parser provided there

Comment: @Sean Bright, this is not a "one-line search and replace" as there is no requirement in XML that the generic identifier and attributes in a tag are on the same line...

Comment: @tadmc, That's where the disconnect is here. You see this as an XML question. It's clearly not. It's a regex question... and it's been asked and answered.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::Twig;
my $t = XML::Twig->new(
                       twig_handlers => {
                           # for repository tags, if it has the enabled
                           # attribute, set it to false.
                           repository => sub {
                               exists $_->{att}->{enabled} &&
                               $_->set_att(enabled => 'false');
                               $_->flush();
                           },
                       },
                      );
$t->parsefile($ARGV[0]);
$t->flush();
```

Seems to work for me. You may want to play with the callback for the repository tag - I'm not sure if you want to always set the enabled attribute to false, even if the attribute isn't there (delete the first line in that callback) or only if the attribute is there.

Okay, it's not a one-liner anymore. But that shouldn't be the requirement if you want it done right. Note that because this is parsing XML now, we require a well-formed XML document and we don't care if the repository tag is spread out over multiple lines, or if there is more than one on a line, or what other attributes it has, etc.

And it also doesn't fall in to your "regex" tag on your question. But that's because I think that tag is making this into an XY problem.